# How to detect key intersection points on sports court using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation, hough-transform

I'm trying to detect the key intersection points of lines on a sports court to allow me to use homography to map a player's position in the camera frame to the corresponding position on a 2D model of the court. The camera position and environment details such as lighting will vary.

My current approach has been to use Canny edge detection and Hough Transform to detect the lines then to use kmeans to group them into horizontal/vertical groups. Once I obtain the key points (court floor corners and intersection points of service lines) I know I can use `findHomography` to obtain the perspective transform for the court. My problems are:

1. Even if I get the intersection points for all the lines, given the camera position (and therefore frame rotation) is not fixed how can I know which lines/intersection points are which? Is there a technique to take the intersections and try and fit them to a model court? I have the exact dimensions of the court floor which is the area I care about.
2. There's lots of "noise" created when using `HoughLines` and `HoughLinesP` - see image below. What would be the best way to merge these lines? Or if fitting to a model is that not a problem?
3. Is this the best modern approach or would attempting something like training a CV model to do segmentation be a better approach?

Sample output from Input/HoughLines/HoughLinesP (L to R):
[image: sample output]